# If 'mat-option' is an Angular component, then verify that

Tags: angular

**Module where component placed:**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [DashboardComponent, DocumentFormComponent],
    imports: [CommonModule, MaterialModule, DashboardRoutingModule],
})
export class DashboardModule {}
```

**MaterialModule is:**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        DragDropModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        DragDropModule,
    ],
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

DashboardComponent is:

```
 <div class="document-block__fields__field">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>{{fieldDefinition.title}}</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" placeholder={{fieldDefinition.title}} autocomplete="off"
            [(ngModel)]="fieldDefinition.fieldvalue">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

How to fix it if module has material module also material module has export.

As you can see I use material elements in component.

So I get this error:

> 1. If 'mat-option' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>    2. If 'mat-option' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message

Comment: From where did you import `MatSelectModule`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA  to schema.

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
    
    @NgModule({
        declarations: [DashboardComponent, DocumentFormComponent],
        imports: [CommonModule, MaterialModule, DashboardRoutingModule],
        schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    export class DashboardModule {}
```